# Using different domain for development and production in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I'm working on AngularJS single page application that consume REST services. The front-end application is developed separately from the back-end and therefore during development we've to hardcode the domain name in the URLs for AJAX calls (we've enabled CORS). But in the case of production everything is running in the same domain and hence hardcoding the domain name looks little bad. Is there we can use the domain name in urls for ajax calls during development and in production don't hardcode the domain name? I'm using gulp.

Comment: I have used [gulp-ng-constant](https://github.com/guzart/gulp-ng-constant) in several occasions. Then, I implement an `$http` [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) that prepends the "API URL" (configured with gulp-ng-constant) to the HTTP calls.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea to me. I'll try that.

Comment: If you post that as an answer I can upvote or accept as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of using [gulp-ng-constant](https://github.com/guzart/gulp-ng-constant) with an `$http` [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#interceptors):

The following task in `gulpfile.js` will generate the file `target/build/scripts/_config.js` with the contents `angular.module('globals', []).constant('apiContextPath', '...');`:

```
gulp.task('app.ngconstant', [], function() {
    var ngConstant = require('gulp-ng-constant'),
    var rename = require('gulp-rename');

    return
        ngConstant({
            constants: {
                apiContextPath: '.' // TODO Devise a way to set per environment; eg command line
            },
            name: 'globals',
            stream: true
        })
        .pipe(rename('_config.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('target/build/scripts'));
});
```

Obviously you need to include the generated file in your (packed/minified) code.

Something along the following code will configure the `$httpProvider` to prepend the `apiContextPath` to all requests that start with `'/api/'` (i.e. our REST endpoints):

```
angular.module(...).config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['globals', function(globals) {
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                if( config.url.indexOf('/api/') === 0 ) {
                    config.url = globals.apiContextPath + config.url;
                }
                return config;
            }
        };
    }]);
}]);
```

(There are quite a few other configuration options, so this is just an example from an older project I worked on.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already, you could pass your gulp build a parameter to build in production or development mode.

Based on that flag you can set a `baseUrl` property in your gulpfile that is used to include a script (using `gulp-insert`) into your javascript build before all of your angular scripts:

```
'window.baseUrl = ' + baseUrl
```

Then you could have a constant in your application that your services use to get the `baseUrl`:

```
angular.module('YourModule').constant('baseUrl', window.baseUrl);
```

Comment: In this case during development the css/images also comes from another domain right? I want the css/images to be load from the local machine only the AJAX calls has to hit the different domain.

Comment: You could use `baseUrl` wherever you want in your application. It wouldn't affect loading of the images unless you wanted it to. So in your services you could inject it, and build the urls like `$http.get(baseUrl + '/api/endpoint')`

Comment: I see a problem there. Currently there are lot of urls in lot of files and it's quite difficult to go and change each one to prepend the baseurl.

Comment: Fair enough. That gulp plugin Nikos suggested seems like an easier way to go about it.